# Can I make a program autorun from a flash drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autorun

I want to know if it is possible to put a program on a flash drive and use an `autorun.inf` file to set the program to run as soon as the drive is inserted and ready. I know how to do this for optical disks with an ISO  on to it, but not with a flash drive or any other removable media.

Even more specifically, if this is possible, can this be made universal for various versions of Windows? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Most OS's block this USB auto run by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A regular flash drive cannot](https://superuser.com/questions/224255/usb-flash-drive-autorun), but it can [identify as a CD drive](http://www.visualdesigning.com/articles/how-to-create-autorun-usb-drive/) in order to trick the OS into enabling autorun. This is the technique used by [U3 flashdrives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3_(software)), which identify as a composite device consisting of a "CD drive" for the U3 software, and a removable storage device for data.

Comment: Good to know, thank you for your information.